# How can I get variable from a different file using user input?

Tags: python

I'm working on a fun project with my friend and we're trying to figure out how to get a specific variable from a file using user input.

Example:

In pokemonList.py file

```
charmander = "fire"
squirtle = "water"
```

In main.py file

```
import pokemonList
pokemon = input("select a pokemon: ")
print(pokemonList.pokemon)
```

When I try that the program thinks I'm trying to get a variable called "pokemon" from the file.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You want to use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  Or perhaps something more advanced like the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that names are unique, I think a dictionary is a sensible approach:

in pokemonList.py:

```
pokemon = {"charmander" : "fire",
           "squirtle" : "water"}
```

in main.py:

```
import pokemonList

pokemon = input("select a pokemon: ")
print(pokemon, " ", pokemonList.pokemon[pokemon])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! We've swapped all the variables and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you need.

1. Instead of saving the variables just as variables, save them as a dictionary, like this:

pokemonList.py:

```py
pokemon = {"charmander": "fire",
           "squirtle": "water"}
```

main.py:

```py
import pokemonList

pokemon = input("select a pokemon: ")
print(pokemonList.pokemon[pokemon])
```

2. You can use the `eval` function to get the values (very unsafe and not recommended):

pokemonList.py:

```py
charmander = "fire"
squirtle = "water"
```

main.py:

```py
import pokemonList
pokemon = input("select a pokemon: ")
print(eval("pokemonList."+pokemon))
```

Comment: The `eval` approach is poor design. Code shouldn't be tied down to what its variable names are literally and `eval` is a security hole, not to mention slow. Looking the user input in `globals` is a bit better but still pretty awful.

Comment: Option 2 is _extremely_ unsafe. Probably it's "ok" for your current task, but not doing things like `eval(input())` is the bare minimum of program security.

Comment: Correct, this is why it is the second way, but I will add that this is unsafe and not recommended.

Comment: Or just remove it entirely ;-)

Comment: Here's an example string you can input to see the severity here: `charmander.index(eval('__import__("os").system("echo I wiped your harddrive")'))`.